# Different values for different comboboxes in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Bear with me, as I'm new to WPF.I have a datagrid which contains comboboxes.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="131,93,13,101" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="dgData_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="Subject" Width="100"/>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Subject" x:Name="comboboxColumn1"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

And I use the following code to load different itemsources depending on which combobox is clicked on by the user:

```
   private void dgData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (dgData.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            comboboxColumn1.ItemsSource = resolution;
        } else if (dgData.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            comboboxColumn1.ItemsSource = codec;    
        }
    }
```

How I bind dgData:

```
  List<TicketInfo> ticketsList = new List<TicketInfo> 
        {
            new TicketInfo{ Subject="File", Status="Open"},
            new TicketInfo{ Subject="Resolution", Status="Assigned"},

        };
        dgData.ItemsSource = ticketsList;

  public class TicketInfo
         {
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
         }
```

Now I also need to retrieve the value of the combobox once the user chooses the value. Is there a more elegant way to load different items in different comboboxes and retrieving the value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't show how you bind dgData.

```
public class TicketInfo
{
   public string Subject { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public List<string> SubjectSubList { get; set; }
}
```

Bind the second column to SubjectSubList

When you build List ticketsList just put resolution in the first SubjectSubList and codec in the second.

Comment: Thanks, edited how I bind dgData. So I change "public string Status { get; set; }" to "public List<string> SubjectSubList { get; set; }" ? But how do I retrieve the value of the selected item in combobox?

Comment: I don't know how to be more clear.  You bind the DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource to SubjectSubList.

Comment: but that doesn't allow me to retrieve the selected item in combobox, does it? Can you please show and example of how to retrieve the combobox value?

Comment: Yes it does.  You have previously asked the same question and rejected the correct answer.  Grow up and use the software how it works rather than how you want it to work.

Comment: Is it difficult to show me how to retrieve the combobox value? Don't answer unless you know.