# Different itemssource for different combobox in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different values for different comboboxes in Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182777/different-values-for-different-comboboxes-in-datagrid)

I have two comboboxes added to a `DataGrid` using the code below:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="191" Width="313" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{x:Null}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Hello"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Name="Combo1" Height="22"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <ComboBox Name="Combo1"/>
    <ComboBox Name="Combo2"/>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, how do I add two different itemsources to these two columns?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**In Xaml**, you can directly define the `ItemSource` this way:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo1" ItemsSource="{Binding Homes, Mode=OneWay}" 
   DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Where `Homes` corresponds to the `Property` defined in the `ViewModel` that is associated with the `DataContext` of the current `window`/`control`.

**In Code-Behind**, you can define the `ItemSource` this way:

```
Combo1.ItemSource = Homes;
```

Reference: [WPF ComboBox and DataBinding: DataContext, ItemsSource, DisplayMemberPath, SelectedItem, SelectedValue & SelectedValuePath](http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/09/wpf-combobox-and-databinding-datacontext-itemssource-displaymemberpath-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath/)

Comment: I tried the following and it doesn't work:  List<string> lss = new List<string>();  lss.Add("hej");
            lss.Add("hej2");
            lss.Add("hej3");
            Combo1.ItemsSource = lss;

Comment: It should work as it is working at my side without any issue, what are you doing exactly?

Comment: I am pasting the XAML in my first post so the datagrid shows up, and then I paste the combo1.itemssource in code-behind. The combobox still shows up empty :(

Answer (score 0):

just get the combox by name and add different itemsource  to it

```
Combo1.ItemsSource = listSource1;
Combo2.ItemsSource = listSource2;
```

Comment: I tried the following and it doesn't work: List<string> lss = new List<string>(); lss.Add("hej"); lss.Add("hej2"); lss.Add("hej3"); Combo1.ItemsSource = lss;